# Simulating :active with jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

For hover, I do this:

```
$('.btn').hover(function (event) {
   $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Is there any similar workaround for :active? Need it for the damned IE6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery mousedown() to simulate this.

Look at the example here:

http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/#example-0

```
$('.btn').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
}).mouseup(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres some info on here:

http://csscreator.com/node/31976